# Mongodb Error withTransaction: Given transaction number 1 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is -1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

Mongoose documentation says to use **withTransaction** for best practice while using transactions, because it will handle all of these

1. Creating a transaction
2. Committing the transaction if it succeeds
3. Aborting the transaction if your operation throws
4. Retrying in the event of a transient transaction error.

But **withTransaction** function doing infinite retries. the errors which it throws are below. As you can see from Error #1, it retried 1998 times and keep doing the retries.

Is there a problem with my code? Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Setup:**
MongoDB Server 4.4.x: mongoose ^5.10.0

**Code:**

```
try {
      const session = await db.startSession();
      await session.withTransaction(() => {
        console.log('transaction in progress')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          Promise.all([
            Model1().bulkWrite([...], { session }),
            Model2().bulkWrite([...], { session })
          ])
            .then(resp => {
              console.log('bulk write resolved successfully')
              resolve(resp)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('transaction error', error)
              reject(error)
            })
        })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('withTransaction: ', error)
      throw error
    } finally {
      session.endSession()
    }
```

**Error #1:**

```
transaction in progress

transaction error MongoError: Given transaction number 1998 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is 1997
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:299:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at processIncomingData (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1634234124 },
  ok: 0,
  code: 251,
  codeName: 'NoSuchTransaction',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1634234124 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'TransientTransactionError' }
}
```

**Error #2:**

```
transaction in progress

transaction error MongoError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:299:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at processIncomingData (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1634234124 },
  ok: 0,
  code: 112,
  codeName: 'WriteConflict',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1634234124 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'TransientTransactionError' }
}
```

Comment: Idk if its related, but shouldnt Promise.all take an array?

Comment: Once you return the promise from that function, the session is closed because you are not in the scope of `withTransaction` anymore. You are mixing `async/await` pattern with promises and this is a bad practice at first. I guess that when you `await` on the promise you return, the session that is trying to read is already expired, that is probably why it gives you the first error message. Where does the second message come from?

Comment: withTransaction then retry after getting error#1 and then it gets error#2. withTransaction keep on retrying in case of TransientTransactionError